# has_no_attribute error python

Tags: python, serialization

I am trying to send serialized objects over a network and until today, that worked fine.

Now I have an error:

```
@staticmethod                   
def processkeys(self):
    '''
    This method has to be static as it is used as a tarked for a Thread.
    All it does by now is receive a mouseAndKeyWrapperobject from the client and 
    set this instances object to it.
    '''
    logging.getLogger(__name__).warning("keys processed")
    print("here")
    sock = self.sock
    Id = self.id
    from modules.logic import game
    self.myPlayer  = game.get_player()
    while True:
        try:
            myMakw = sock.recv(4096)
            self.makw = loads(myMakw)
            self.movePlayers(self.makw)
        except:
            logging.getLogger("nothing from Client")

        self.wrap.addPlayer(self.myPlayer)
        wrapToSend = dumps(self.wrap, 2)

        sock.sendall(wrapToSend)
```

works fine until the line before the last:
The dumping produces the following error message:

```
    wrapToSend = dumps(self.wrap, 2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'py_decode_TypedWritable_from_bam_stream'
```

I have serialized and deserialized objects, even self-written objects, with this method before without ever getting anything like this.
Even google does not seem to know that particular error message (zero hits).

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: It sounds like `wrap` isn't what you think it is. Try `print(self.wrap)` and see what you get.

Comment: well it DOES work fine as long as I do not try to add a Player to the list, hence I guess Players are not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `classmethod` or `staticmethod` decorators, you shouldn't have a `self` parameter. Question now is in what context this is called and what this `self` actually refers to - after all, Python doesn't enforce any particular meaning on parameters named `self`. I have a feeling that you are mixing up class properties and instance properties, too, which is why this didn't fail before, but that's hard to tell without some actual example code.